# Umbraco / TeamCity BuildAgent nullReference error showing in Event Viewer

Tags: umbraco

I'm noticing a strange error cropping up regularly with a site I've inherited the maintenance of from a former colleague.

Does it ring any bells for any of you out there?

It's an umbraco v 4.0.4.2 site, and TeamCity is most definitely NOT installed on this machine.

Here's the message:

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://www.[[some website name]].co.uk/default.aspx 
    Request path: /default.aspx 
    User host address: [[some ip address]]
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 1

```
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Is impersonating: False 

Stack trace:
```

at umbraco.requestHandler..ctor(XmlDocument _umbracoContent, String url) in d:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7380c184e9fcd3ea\umbraco\presentation\requestHandler.cs:line 230

at umbraco.UmbracoDefault.Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7380c184e9fcd3ea\umbraco\presentation\default.aspx.cs:line 113

at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)

at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)

at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Custom event details:

For more information, see Help and Support Center at

Answer (score 0):

The reference to Teamcity is just telling where the original file was compiled from in the filesystem.

It is most likely that you are missing a dll in the bin folder.